# How to pass instance of a model to another model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to populate dbkey column from parent table on the form, where foreign table values are input.
WHile providing a value I get the following error - "csg_ch_servers.DBParentCustomerKey" must be a "csg_ch_customer" instance.
Could someone help me out?

**model.py**

```
class csg_ch_customer(models.Model):
    DBKey=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    CustomerName=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table="csg_ch_customer"
    def  __unicode__(self):
        return self.DBKey
    def __init__(self):
        return self.DBKey

class csg_ch_servers(models.Model):
    DBKey=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    DBParentCustomerKey=models.ForeignKey(csg_ch_customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        db_table="csg_ch_servers"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.DBParentCustomerKey
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.DBParentCustomerKey
```

**form.py**

```
class csg_ch_customer_form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model  = models.csg_ch_customer
        fields = "__all__"

class csg_ch_servers_form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model  = models.csg_ch_servers
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['DBParentCustomerKey'].queryset = models.csg_ch_customer.objects.values_list('DBKey', flat=True)
```

views.py

```
def register_ser(request):
    form=Aforms.csg_ch_servers_form()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=Aforms.csg_ch_servers_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('Admin/NewServer.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'Admin/NewServer.html',{'form':form})
    return render(request,'Admin/NewServer.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: It's very hard to read your code because you have not followed Python or Django conventions for variable naming or spacing. I suggest you take a look at the PEP8 standard. Aside from that, why are you manually setting the queryset attribute for your `DBParentCustomerKey` in `csg_ch_servers_form` to a values list of IDs? - that is likely to be your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the PEP8 standard. Will go through it.

Comment: Regarding the queryset definiton, Im trying to populate the column 'dbkey' of the primary table, in the html page. Like setting up a dropdown from available choices only.

Comment: Yes, but 1. Django already knows how to do that, and 2. What you're giving the field is not actually a queryset, but a values list. What happens if you delete that line?

Comment: If I remove that line - then I see csg_ch_customer object (DBkey). I want to populate in a way such that, the dropdown shows customer name against that particular dbkey.

Comment: You need to customise the string representation of that model. You are currently doing that already in the `__str__` and `__unicode__` methods of those models, but you have it showing the DBkey instead of the name. I suggest you go back and do the official Django tutorial, this is all covered and your Django experience will be much easier if you know the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Your form needs to instanciate your model in your views.
I added few fields to your view, but you need to edit it for your own purpose.

This should be as simple as possible.

```
def register_ser(request,pk):
    yourmodel = models.csg_ch_customer.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form=Aforms.csg_ch_servers_form(instance=yourmodel)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=Aforms.csg_ch_servers_form(request.POST,instance=yourmodel)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('Admin/NewServer.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'Admin/NewServer.html',{'form':form})
    return render(request,'Admin/NewServer.html',{'form':form})
```